# Horizontal Scroll using buttons on angular2

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

So I have this app in angular2 where I need to scroll a component horizontally but with buttons right and left. So I need a function for each button that scroll to right or left the content. I need something like this:
[image]

I tried using `document.getElementById('myscrolldiv').animate({ scrollLeft: "-=" + 250 + "px"; }` but Angular does not recognize the `animate` line.

So I am looking for a diferent way of scroll horizontally using buttons but NOT using jquery. Is there any way to do this in angular?

Here is my html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="side">
    <mat-icon (click)="scrollLeft()">keyboard_arrow_left</mat-icon>
  </div>
  <div id="widgetsContent" class="middle">
    <div class="scrolls">
      <div class="info-widget">
         WIDGET
      </div>
      <div class="info-widget">
         WIDGET
      </div>
      <div class="info-widget">
         WIDGET
      </div>
      <div class="info-widget">
         WIDGET
      </div>
      <div class="info-widget">
         WIDGET
      </div>
      <div class="info-widget">
         WIDGET
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="side">
    <mat-icon (click)="scrollRight()">keyboard_arrow_right</mat-icon>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is my css

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 22.5vh !important;
}

.side {
  width: 50px;
  height: 22.5vh !important;
}

.middle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 22.5vh !important;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

So, how do I scroll right and left pushing the buttons? please help.

Comment: Where is your JS code?

Comment: I am using typescript in the angular componet. The function scrollLeft() and scrollRight() are empty for now but I need a scroll funtion without using JQuery

Comment: You wrote: "I tried using `document.getElementById('myscrolldiv')`".    But I do not see any element with `id="myscrolldiv"` in your HTML code. Do you really understand what you're doing?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Import ViewChild and ElementRef to get elemenet refrence.

use #localvariable as shown here, `<div #widgetsContent class="middle">`

get element in component, `@ViewChild('widgetsContent', { read: ElementRef }) public widgetsContent: ElementRef<any>;`

change scrollvalue,  `this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollTo({ left: (this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollLeft + 150), behavior: 'smooth' });`

An example is shown below

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
                <div class="container">
                <div style="float: left">
                    <button (click)="scrollLeft()">left</button>
                </div>

                <div #widgetsContent class="middle">
                    <div class="info-widget">
                    WIDGET
                    </div>
                    <div class="info-widget">
                    WIDGET
                    </div>
                    <div class="info-widget">
                    WIDGET
                    </div>
                    <div class="info-widget">
                    WIDGET
                    </div>
                    <div class="info-widget">
                    WIDGET
                    </div>
                    <div class="info-widget">
                    WIDGET
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div style="float: right">
                    <button (click)="scrollRight()">right</button>
                </div>
                </div>
            `,
    styles: [`
      .info-widget {
        width: 31.75%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .middle {
        float: left;
        width: 90%;
        overflow: auto;
        /*will change this to hidden later to deny scolling to user*/
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
            `]
})

export class AppComponent { 

  @ViewChild('widgetsContent', { read: ElementRef }) public widgetsContent: ElementRef<any>;

  public scrollRight(): void {
    this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollTo({ left: (this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollLeft + 150), behavior: 'smooth' });
  }

  public scrollLeft(): void {
    this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollTo({ left: (this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollLeft - 150), behavior: 'smooth' });
  }
}
```

Comment: public widgetsContent: ElementRef<any> -  this does not work in Angular 5. Error: type ElementRef is not generic. When I googled the error, people were pointing at upgrading material version but we are not using material at all in our project.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me but i want to display scroll based on screen width. "scrolling.this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollLeft + 150" don't want to hard core this 150

Comment: @Hari9513 You can get scrollWidth dynamically.

`scrollLeft() {
    this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollLeft -= this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollWidth;
}

scrollRight() {
    this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollLeft += this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollWidth;
}`

Answer (score 7):

Consider the following solution

In .html

```
<div #widgetsContent class="custom-slider-main">
    <div class="info-widget">
         WIDGET
      </div>
      <div class="info-widget">
         WIDGET
      </div>
      <div class="info-widget">
         WIDGET
      </div>
      <div class="info-widget">
         WIDGET
      </div>
      <div class="info-widget">
         WIDGET
      </div>
      <div class="info-widget">
         WIDGET
      </div>
</div>
```

In .scss

```
.custom-slider-main{
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;    
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

In .ts

```
@ViewChild('widgetsContent') widgetsContent: ElementRef;
```

And On click of left/right button use the following functions

```
scrollLeft(){
    this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollLeft -= 150;
  }

  scrollRight(){
    this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollLeft += 150;
  }
```