# Angular horizontal scroll with dynamic arrows

Tags: css, angular, scrollview

I want to use horizontal scroll with left and right arrows with dynamically hide and show functionality. 
[Horizontal scroll (with arrows) for Angular package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033432/horizontal-scroll-with-arrows-for-angular-package) This thread here answers it but without dynamic hide/show of arrows. Please reply if someone has idea about it. Thanks.

Here is the code below:
.html

```
  <div class="custom-slider-arrow mt-sm">
    <img src="assets/img/chevron-left.svg" alt="" (click)="scrollLeft()">
  </div> 
    <div #widgetsContent class="custom-slider-main">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let object of statusList">
            <status-card ></status-card>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-slider-arrow mt-sm">
      <img src="assets/img/chevron-right.svg" alt="" (click)="scrollRight()">
      </div>

</div>
```

And .ts file has this code.

```
@ViewChild('widgetsContent',{static:false}) widgetsContent: ElementRef;

scrollLeft(){
  this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollLeft -= 300;
}

scrollRight(){
  this.widgetsContent.nativeElement.scrollLeft += 300;
}
```

.scss file contains

```
.custom-slider-main{
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;    
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.custom-slider-arrow{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    img{
        width: 48px;
        height: 48px;
    }
}
```

Comment: What code do you currently have?

Comment: @KurtHamilton I have updated my question. Kindly have a look.

Answer (score 0):

**1) .ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export class Scroll implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('scrollMenu') scrollMenu: ElementRef;
  rightDisabled: boolean = false;
  leftDisabled: boolean = true;
  constructor(){}

  scrollLeft(){
    this.scrollMenu.nativeElement.scrollLeft -= 150;
    this.checkScroll()
  }

  scrollRight(){
    this.scrollMenu.nativeElement.scrollLeft += 150;
        this.checkScroll();
  }
  
  onScroll(e){
      this.checkScroll();
  }

  checkScroll(){
    this.scrollMenu.nativeElement.scrollLeft==0? this.leftDisabled = true :this.leftDisabled = false;

    let newScrollLeft = this.scrollMenu.nativeElement.scrollLeft;
    let width = this.scrollMenu.nativeElement.clientWidth;
    let scrollWidth = this.scrollMenu.nativeElement.scrollWidth;
    scrollWidth - (newScrollLeft+width)==0? this.rightDisabled = true :this.rightDisabled = false;
  }

}
```

**2) .html file**

```
  <ion-row>
<div class="pull-left mt-sm" (click)="scrollLeft()" [ngClass]="this.leftDisabled ? 'visibility':''"> 
  <ion-icon name="chevron-back-outline" style="font-size: 24px;" ></ion-icon>
</div>
<div class="scroll" scrollX="true" #scrollMenu (scroll)="onScroll($event)" [ngClass]="this.rightDisabled ? 'width':this.leftDisabled?'width':''">
  <div *ngFor="let data of yourDataArray">
        {{data.someData}}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pull-right" (click)="scrollRight()" [ngClass]="this.rightDisabled ? 'visibility':''">
  <ion-icon name="chevron-forward" style="font-size: 24px;" ></ion-icon>
</div></ion-row>
```

**3) .scss file**

```css
.scroll {
    overflow: auto;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    width: 80%; 
    background: var(--ion-primary-bg);
}

.pull-right{
    background: grey;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 10%;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.visibility{
    display: none !important;

}

.pull-left{
    background: grey;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 10%;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.width{
    width:90% !important;
}
```

Comment: is there source code is there